# Создать экземпляр зависимой модели в Ruby on Rails

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Есть проектс с Devise. В зависимостях модели User прописан профиль

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

Соответственно в профиле обратная картина

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании User, автоматически создавался Profile?
Сейчас я сделал такой костыль в ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
      def set_new_user?
        if current_user.role == "new_user"
          profile = Profile.create(user_id: current_user.id)
          flash[:notice] = "Сначала вы должны заполнить свой профиль."
          redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
        end
      end
```

И запихнул как проверку при загрузке других контроллеров. Чую, что за это для меня уже готов котёл в аду, но пока не могу понять, как сделать иначе. Тем более, что этот вариант не работает.
Я так понимаю, что не работает из-за того, что я пытаюсь профиль создать из ApplicationController?

Ещё я пытался создавать профиль, если он отсутствует при редактировании пользователя:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find_or_create_by(user_id: params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Но это тоже не возымело успеха.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так я думаю. Идея в том чтобы инициализировать новым значением, если ещё нету.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_initialize :init
...
def init
  self.profile = Profile.new unless self.profile
end
```

Comment: Это помогло, только вместо before_initialize пришлось использовать after_initialize. Спасибо!

Comment: @Kiro, Да немного попутал, спасибо